# In running vlc from command line in linux, is there a way to launch music to a random entry in the media library?

Tags: command-line-interface, vlc

I have a bash program that launches a seperate vlc instance on the machine for sound generation to create background audio (voice controlled by Mycroft AI). However, I've tried several variations of commands for the launcher to get it to start immediately playing randomly from the media.

First I tried

```
gnome-terminal -- vlc --media-library --one-instance
```

This did nothing.

I then tried

```
gnome-terminal -- vlc ~/Music/music/ --one-instance
```

As this folder is where the sounds were located, but it only opened to one folder in the media library, it was largely stuck there (and any sounds in the media library that weren't in that folder would largely be untouched.)

After this, I tried

```
gnome-terminal -- vlc ~/Music/music/ --media-library --one-instance
```

However, this acted the same as the above command.
I've learned from the first that I likely always need a 'file' to pass in, but I learned from the third that if I do so, it will use that instead of the media library. So, it leaves me with the same question I began with...

How do I launch vlc from the command line to automatically start playing the media library?

Comment: Is `vlc` a must? `mpv` can do this

Comment: Yep, vlc is needed.